# publish artifact overwrite other artifact in Gradle

Tags: groovy, gradle, ivy

I am experimenting with Gradle to build a few jars, rather than maintain a list of classes that hold EJBs so that I can deploy them separately I thought it might be neat to scan the classes when making the jar.

Rather than load the classes and use reflection to get the annotations I thought it may be simpler to scan the classes with asm, hence the chuncky ClassReader in one of the tasks.

I don't think this is the issue so can be ignored, basically I have 2 tasks that I use to define the contents of the jars, both report that different content is going into them via the eachFile print out, however when I look in the publish repository location both files and associated sha1 are identical.

Either Gradle is broken or, more likely, I've done something crazy but can't see what it is, can anyone help?

By the way if I disable the publish of either of the jar files the one that does get created is correct so I think it's something wrong with the publish rather than the jarring up, but could be wrong.

```
// ASM is used to interpret the class files, this avoids having to load all classes in the vm and use reflection
import org.objectweb.asm.*
task ejbJar(type: Jar) {
  //outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
  from "${project.buildDir}/classes/main"
  eachFile { println "EJB server: ${name}" }
  include getEjbClassFiles(project.buildDir)
}

task clientEjbJar(type: Jar) {
  //outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
  from "${project.buildDir}/classes/main/com/company/core/versioner"
  eachFile { println "Client EJB ${name}" }  
  include '**/*'
}

artifacts {    
  archives clientEjbJar
  archives ejbJar
}
String[] getEjbClassFiles(base) {
  def includedFiles = []
  def baseDir = project.file("${base}/classes/main")
  def parentPath = baseDir.toPath()
  if (baseDir.isDirectory()) {
    baseDir.eachFileRecurse(groovy.io.FileType.FILES) { file ->
      if(file.name.endsWith('.class')) {
        //get hold of annotations in there --- org.objectweb.asm.Opcodes.ASM4
        def reader = new ClassReader(file.bytes).accept(
          new ClassVisitor(Opcodes.ASM4) {
            public AnnotationVisitor visitAnnotation(String desc, boolean visible) {
              if(desc.equals("Ljavax/ejb/Stateless;") ||
                desc.equals("Ljavax/ejb/Stateful;")) {
                includedFiles += parentPath.relativize(file.toPath())
              }
              return null //no interest in actually visiting the annotation values
            }
          }, 
          ClassReader.SKIP_DEBUG | ClassReader.EXPAND_FRAMES | ClassReader.SKIP_FRAMES | ClassReader.SKIP_CODE
        )
      }
    }
  }
  return includedFiles
}    

publishing {
  publications {
    mypub(IvyPublication) {
      artifact(ejbJar) {
        name 'ejb' 
      }
      artifact(clientEjbJar) { 
        name 'client-ejb' 
      }
    }
  }
  repositories {
    ivy {
      name 'personal'
      url "${ant['developer.repository']}/"
      layout 'pattern', {
        artifact "[organisation]/[module]/[artifact]/[revision]/[type]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]"
    ivy "[organisation]/[module]/[type]/[revision]/[type]/[type]-[revision].[ext]"
      }
    }   
  }  
}
```

I did break the thing down into a simpler form as I thought it may be a Gradle bug.

The simplified form was:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'ivy-publish'

task bigJar(type: Jar) {
  from "${rootDir}/src/main/resources"
  include '**/*'
}

task smallJar(type: Jar) {
  from "${rootDir}/src/main/resources/A/B"
  include '**/*'
}

group 'ICantBeEmpty'
artifacts {
  archives bigJar
  archives smallJar
}

publishing {
  publications {
    mypub(IvyPublication) {
      artifact(bigJar) { name 'biggie' }
      artifact(smallJar) { name 'smallie' }
    }
    repositories {
  ivy {
    name 'personal'
    url "c:/temp/gradletest"
    layout 'pattern', {
      artifact "[organisation]/[module]/[artifact]/[revision]/[type]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]"
      ivy "[organisation]/[module]/[type]/[revision]/[type]/[type]-[revision].[ext]"
    }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This results in 2 files in c:/temp/gradletest/ICantBeEmpty/report-bug/biggie/unspecified/biggie-unspecified.jar and c:/temp/gradletest/ICantBeEmpty/report-bug/smallie/unspecified/smallie-unspecified.jar
Both of these files are identical, however I think I know why see my later answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst looking at some configurations I noticed some odd behaviour that led me to a resolution of this issue, and it is a Gradle bug.

In my build I had a scratch task doing

```
configurations.archives.artifacts.each { println it }
```

This gave me 5 different lines output, however changing it to this

```
configurations.archives.artifacts.each { println it.file }
```

produced the same filename 5 times.

It turns out this is related to my issue, although the artifacts are there as separate entities the name used to uniquely identify them was the same so the same file was always chosen during a publish.  The name of the artifacts is given by ${baseName}-${appendix}-${version}-${classifier}.${extension} by default in the java plugin.  This means that if neither appendix or classifier is specified then the artifact will have the same name.

I tested this using the above sample code by adding an appendix name

```
task bigJar(type: Jar) {
  appendix = 'big'
  from "${rootDir}/src/main/resources"
  include '**/*'
}

task smallJar(type: Jar) {
  appendix = 'small'
  from "${rootDir}/src/main/resources/A/B"
  include '**/*'
}
```

Using this rather than the code from the question produces 2 different jars.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a complete answer but is a good enough work around, if I add a new publication definition I can publish the artifacts that I want to to the location that I want, the only downside is that it will create another gradle task which isn't ideal.

```
   publications {
      mypub(IvyPublication) {
        artifact(ejbJar) {
          name 'ejb' 
        }
      }
      newpub(IvyPublication) {
        artifact(clientEjbJar) { 
          name 'client-ejb' 
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The above answer works in the short term, however does reveal yet another short coming in the Gradle world [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16281512/ivy-module-xml-doesnt-contain-all-artifacts-when-gradle-publish-is-used)

Not sure Gradle is all it could be at the moment, and so far no one has answered my questions so maybe it's not that actively developed!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert in this part of Gradle, but the functionality you are using is marked as "[incubating](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/publishing_ivy.html)"; you are using the new publishing feature which might or might not be complete. Perhaps you should use the [old way](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/artifact_management.html) of doing things. You also seem to be mixing both ways by using the `artifacts` closure.

Comment: thanks for the interest but the 'old way' link shows me exactly what I am already doing aside from the fact that I am using an ivy repo not a flat file.  Because something is in the state of incubating doesn't mean it shouldn't be used and issue raised about it, this is the essence of open source evolving so quickly.  I have actually identified the issue now as the name used to locate artifacts within a configuration is not unique and will post a complete description to save other Gradle users the same hassle.