# ivy module.xml doesn't contain all artifacts when gradle publish is used

Tags: gradle, ivy

I believe this may be related to [publish artifact overwrite other artifact in Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15879900/publish-artifact-overwrite-other-artifact-in-gradle)

if I have a set of publications such as

```
publishing {
  publications {
    serverpub(IvyPublication) {
      artifact(ejbJar) {
        name 'ejb' 
      }
    }
    clientpub(IvyPublication) {
      artifact(clientEjbJar) { 
        name 'client-ejb' 
      }
    }
    modulepub(IvyPublication) {
      artifact(moduleJar) {
        name 'cname-core'
      }
    }
    persistpub(IvyPublication) {
      artifact(persistenceJar) {
        name 'core-entities'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

After doing a 'publish' the

```
<Project Name>/ivy/<version>/ivy/ivy-<version>.xml
```

file only contains the first item in the list of publications

```
<artifact name="ejb" type="jar" ext="jar"/>
```

If I make all of the artifacts fall under a single publication ie. serverpub then the ivy.xml file will contain all of the correct artifacts but the jar files themselves are all identical thus I have the same error as the previous link.

Am I doing something wrong because so far Gradle has proved a pain in the parenthesis for publishing artifacts.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared four independent publications, each of which will produce its own module descriptor. To produce an Ivy module containing multiple artifacts, you'll have to list them under the same publication. Regarding the "Jar files are identical" problem, a minimal self-contained reproducible example would help.

Note that the new `ivy-publish` plugin that you are using is still *incubating* and may have shortcomings. We are grateful for feedback to make it better. The best place to reach Gradle developers and experts is http://forums.gradle.org.